# FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK not working in API 31?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm upgrading my app target SDK from API 30 to API 31.
I have an ever-displayed notification during the execution of my app. This notification when clicked, opens the app if it is in background. The ContentIntent of my Notification triggers the execution of:

```
...
Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(myIntent)
...
```

So,this code works as expected on my app that targets API 31 when executed on API 30 smartphone (the app goes foreground if it was in background). Instead, if running on API 31 smartphone, the app remains in background. I haven't found anything concerning e behavior change of this kind for apps that target api 31 on api 31 smartphone, so I'm wondering what should i do to put the app on foreground.

Comment: Use an activity `PendingIntent` in your notification. My guess is that you are using a "trampoline" (e.g., a broadcast `PendingIntent` that is trying to call `startActivity()`), and that is no longer supported.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my issue. Going to upvote once I have enough reputation

Comment: @siruvio if it's not a big trouble for you, can you write the code you used to solve this issue? Thanks

Comment: @siruvio You can answer here and I will accept your answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73459898/unable-to-get-android-app-back-into-foreground-for-api-31

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, your existing code uses a "trampoline": a non-activity `PendingIntent` that runs code that turns around and starts an activity. That is no longer supported. Instead, use an activity `PendingIntent` that starts your `MyActivity` directly.

Comment: Hello, I have the same problem. I use PendintIntent with this code: pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73459898/unable-to-get-android-app-back-into-foreground-for-api-31