# Unable to get android app back into foreground for API 31

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent, background-foreground

I need to get the app from background into foreground. I managed to make this work for versions below 31 by using this code:

```
public static void bringApplicationToFront(Context context)
{  
    Log.d("bringApplicationToFront");

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, SplashActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = null;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity
                (context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
    }
    else {
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity
                (context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    }

    try
    {
        pendingIntent.send();
    }
    catch (PendingIntent.CanceledException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

SplashActivity is my root Activity. I tried this with a BroadcastReceiver and also by using background thread which runs the code with a delay.

I call this method from Application class like this:

```
@Override
public void onTrimMemory(int level)
{
    super.onTrimMemory(level);
    if (level == TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN) {
        Print.e("App is background"); 
        bringApplicationToFront(); 
    }
}
```

How can I make this work for API 31?

Answer (score 0):

Android has tightened up the restriction around launching an `Activity` from a background process (`Service`, `BroadcastReceiver`, etc.). You can read about this here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts#exceptions

Probably the only thing you can do is request `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission as a workaround. Personally I think this is a terrible hack and Android will probably close this loophole in a future version.

Comment: Hello, thanks for taking the time to reply. I followed the link you provided and the third statement says: "The app has an activity in the back stack of an existing task on the Recents screen". That means, even with the new restrictions, it's still possible to achieve what I am trying to do.